# How to produce a jpeg plot using a function?

Tags: r, plot

I have following example code for producing the box plots for a data frame with categorical variables.

```
DF<-data.frame("A"=rnorm(20,3,0.2),"B"=rnorm(20,2,0.1),"C"=rnorm(20,2,0.3))
DF<-stack(DF)
BPFunc <- function ( PDataSet,Cat, PData, PTitle,XTitle, YTitle,PlotName) {
  arguments <- as.list(match.call())
  PData = eval(arguments$PData, PDataSet)
  Cat = eval(arguments$Cat, PDataSet)
  PDataSet<-data.frame(Cat=Cat,PData=PData)
  bp <- ggplot(PDataSet, aes(x = Cat, y =  as.numeric( PData) , fill = factor( Cat)))
  bp <- bp + geom_boxplot(notch = F)
  bp <- bp + labs(title=PTitle, x=XTitle, y =YTitle)
  bp <- bp + theme_bw()
  bp

 }
```

The above function can be successfully work using:

```
BPFunc(DF,  ind  ,  values  ,"My Box","Categories","Value")
```

Now I want to able my code to save the plot in a jpeg device using following modifications:

```
BPFunc <- function ( PDataSet,Cat, PData, PTitle,XTitle, YTitle,PlotName) {
  arguments <- as.list(match.call())
  PData = eval(arguments$PData, PDataSet)
  Cat = eval(arguments$Cat, PDataSet)
  PDataSet<-data.frame(Cat=Cat,PData=PData)
  bp <- ggplot(PDataSet, aes(x = Cat, y =  as.numeric( PData) , fill = factor( Cat)))
  bp <- bp + geom_boxplot(notch = F)
  bp <- bp + labs(title=PTitle, x=XTitle, y =YTitle)
  bp <- bp + theme_bw()

  jpeg(PlotName, width=4, height=3, units="in", res=600 ) 
  par(mfrow = c(1,1), mgp=c(2, 0.5, 0),oma = c(4,3,4,3) + 0.1, mar = c(3,3,1,1)+0.1,cex=0.5   )
  bp
  graphics.off()
 }
```

As is my expectation I want from the function to save the plot in PlotName.jpeg file and also I need the plot characteristics can be controlled by par() function. But the produced jpeg device is empty when I call function:

```
BPFunc(DF,  ind  ,  values  ,"My Box","Categories","Value","MyPlot.jpeg")
```

As an alternative I know that I can use print() function as follows:

```
     BPFunc <- function ( PDataSet,Cat, PData, PTitle,XTitle, YTitle,PlotName) {
  arguments <- as.list(match.call())
  PData = eval(arguments$PData, PDataSet)
  Cat = eval(arguments$Cat, PDataSet)
  PDataSet<-data.frame(Cat=Cat,PData=PData)
  bp <- ggplot(PDataSet, aes(x = Cat, y =  as.numeric( PData) , fill = factor( Cat)))
  bp <- bp + geom_boxplot(notch = F)
  bp <- bp + labs(title=PTitle, x=XTitle, y =YTitle)
  bp <- bp + theme_bw()

  jpeg(PlotName, width=4, height=3, units="in", res=600 ) 
  par(mfrow = c(1,1), mgp=c(2, 0.5, 0),oma = c(4,3,4,3) + 0.1, mar = c(3,3,1,1)+0.1,cex=0.5   )
  print(bp)
  graphics.off()
 }
```

But when we use print() the plot characteristics can not be controlled by par() function. in another word par() function will not work with print().
please help me know how I can produce the plot while I can use par() to adjust the plot characteristics?
Thanks

Comment: for ggplots you have to use `ggsave(..., device = "jpeg"")`. How to? See `?ggsave()`

Comment: Dear Jimbou thanks, but the results is similar to print(), and yet I can not able to change plot with par() arguments.

Comment: Of course not. ggplots can't be changed using `par`. Use `... + theme()` instead. In addtion try the examples here `?ggsave()`. On my system everything is working like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
BPFunc <- function (PDataSet,Cat, PData, PTitle,XTitle, YTitle,PlotName) {
  arguments <- as.list(match.call())
  PData = eval(arguments$PData, PDataSet)
  Cat = eval(arguments$Cat, PDataSet)
  PDataSet<-data.frame(Cat=Cat,PData=PData)
  bp <- ggplot(PDataSet, aes(x = Cat, y =  as.numeric( PData) , fill = factor( Cat)))
  bp <- bp + geom_boxplot(notch = F)
  bp <- bp + labs(title=PTitle, x=XTitle, y =YTitle)
  bp <- bp + theme_bw()
  bp
  ggsave(PlotName, width=4, height=3, units="in", dpi=600)
}

BPFunc(DF,  ind  ,  values  ,"My Box","Categories","Value","MyPlot.jpeg")
```